# How do I fix this image upload error in my website? Site is built on Python

Tags: python, django, file-upload, importerror

My site, which is built on Python/Postgresql with django, has an area where you can upload an image. When I try to upload an image on it, nothing happens and I receive this error message notification via e-mail:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File 
>   ".. /lib/python/django/core/handlers/b
>   ase.py
>   ", line 85, in get_response
>      response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File 
>   “../lib/python/django/contrib/auth/de
>   corators.py
>   ", line 67, in **call**
>      return self.view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File 
>   ".. /app/bmwrr/views/assessment.py
>   ", line 231, in upload_assessment_media
>      import Image
>
> ImportError: No module named Image
>
> ,
>   POST:,
>   COOKIES:{'sessionid': '1918628422885ccc8265fe7f9229332f'},
>   META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '1741174',
>   'CONTENT_TYPE': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
>   WebKitFormBoundary5S1a4kvt7BfnTMgl',
>   'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/home/bmwrr/www.sitename.com/app/bmwrr',
>   'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/
>   xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
>   'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
>   'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
>   'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH': '1741174',
>   'HTTP_COOKIE': 'sessionid=1918628422885ccc8265fe7f9229332f',
>   'HTTP_HOST': 'sitename.com',
>   'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://sitename.com',
>   'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://sitename.com/assessment/4127/',
>   'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/
>   536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5',
>   'PATH_INFO': '/assessment/upload/4127/',
>   'PATH_TRANSLATED': '../app/bmwrr/assessment/upload/4127/' 
>   ,
>   'QUERY_STRING': '',
>   'REDIRECT_STATUS': '200',
>   'REDIRECT_URI': '/app.fcgi/assessment/upload/4127/',
>   'REMOTE_ADDR': '108.36.115.245',
>   'REMOTE_PORT': '49482',
>   'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
>   'REQUEST_URI': '/assessment/upload/4127/',
>   'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/home/bmwrr/www.sitename.com/app/bmwrr/app.fcgi' 
>   ,
>   'SCRIPT_NAME': '/app.fcgi',
>   'SERVER_ADDR': '108.179.XXX.XXX',
>   'SERVER_NAME': ‘sitename.com',
>   'SERVER_PORT': '80',
>   'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
>   'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'lighttpd/1.4.28',
>   'wsgi.errors': ,
>   'wsgi.input': ,
>   'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
>   'wsgi.multithread': True,
>   'wsgi.run_once': False,
>   'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
>   'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>

Comment: You're attempting to import a module called `Image` that the namespace is not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neeed to install [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), if you have installed pip, you only need to install it with:

```
pip install pil
```

But do you could need some libraries like libjpeg62-dev

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'm having some library issues now, even after installing the jpeg devel ones, but I'll put that up in another post.